# Determine if a url matches a Route, and pull out the terms if it does

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2, routes

I've got a big old log file I'm trying to break down in terms of routes.

Essentially, I'm getting input of a path (`/questions/31415` for example) and a list of all the registered [Routes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.routing.route.aspx).  What I want out is a `Route` and the parameters specified in the route (so in, `/questions/{id}/{answer}` I'd get `id` and `answers` out).

I've got a working solution that basically generates a nasty bit of regex on the fly with named groups to do matching and parsing all-in-one.  My gut tells me this is a brittle way to do it, and frankly there has to be a better way, right?

Comment: Are you doing this in a large batch where performance is important, or one at a time, where you favor simplicity?

Comment: @Nick - Large batches, but rarely.  Simplicity and robustness are more important than performance.  I am currently dynamically generating regex for each and every log entry, with acceptable performance.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but I believe SO encodes the `/` in the question title, so is just simple chunking in an array an option, I'm sure I'm missing some other factor, but it seems like a `.split("/")` is the simplest solution here, do you have a factor prohibiting this?

Comment: @Nick - I gave the `/questions/{id}` route as an example, there are more complicated routes in the actual site.

Comment: Ah gotcha, there's that other shoe I was looking for :)

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question, but on the off chance someone else gets here via Google, I asked and answered my own question on this same subject [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4748342/how-to-determine-if-an-arbitrary-url-matches-a-defined-route/4749840#4749840).

Answer (score 0):

Would the Routing Debugger help? Comes with sample code too.

http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/13/url-routing-debugger.aspx

Comment: To adapt this I'd have to fake a HttpContext, which is much more trouble than its worth; and arguably uglier than my current solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is very similar to the PathParameterFilter often used with spring/REST.
I don't have a link to the source any more, but it has the regular expressions you need to pull things out.
http://www.carbonfive.com/community/archives/2007/06/parameterized_rest_urls_with_spring_mvc.html