# How to get route url properties by route name using C# code?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

As we know, a route is mapped in `Global.asax` file, like:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

There is a method/class where I can access route url properties name by providing a route name ?

For example, for `Default`, I want to call something like

```
public object[] GetRoutePropertiesByName(string name) {
    // process here the `controller`, `action`, `id` // there might be also other values
}
```

Comment: Check out [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4748342/how-to-determine-if-an-arbitrary-url-matches-a-defined-route/4749840). The `RouteInfo` class provides route information based on an url.

Answer (score 2):

This is how you can get a route by name:

```
RouteTable.Routes[routeName]
```

From there you can get some of the route properties:

```
var route = RouteTable.Routes[routeName] as Route;
if (route != null)
{
    var url = route.Url;        
    var controller = route.Defaults["controller"] as string;
    var action = route.Defaults["action"] as string;
    // ...
}
```