# How to get route values for any url in asp.net core?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I need to get the route values for an arbitrary URL in ASP.NET MVC Core.

It could be something like this SO question: [How to determine if an arbitrary URL matches a defined route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4748342/how-to-determine-if-an-arbitrary-url-matches-a-defined-route/4749840), because I haven't found any direct way to do it.

And I haven't been able to do it with that approach either.

It looks like once I have an HttpContext with a Request for the url, it's easy to get the route values, and looking at the source code for [aspnet/Hosting](https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting) in GitHub I got to the point where HttpContextFactory gets created, but that was it, just couldn't go any further!

Does someone know how to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you share with us what you tried. It's hard to guess what you're trying to solve.

Comment: You should probably also check out the aspnet/Routing repository :)

Comment: I'm trying to get the RouteValues out of the referrer url from the Request object, to implement a simple view navigation scheme.

It's as if I createed a new Request object with the referrer url and get the RouteValues out of it.

Answer (score 3):

Ref: Net6
You can install the package and use the namespace
`using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing;`

then you can get route values like this

```
var routeData = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.GetRouteData(); ;
var namedRouteValue = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.GetRouteValue("route-key");
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this an older post, but this is what I did in order to get RouteData from a RouteCollection running in an ASP.NET MVC Core app based on a URL.

```cs
public async Task<ActionResult> GetRouteDataForUrl([FromQuery(Name = "url")] string url)
{
  var uri = new Uri(url);

  var httpContext = new DefaultHttpContext();
  httpContext.Request.Path = uri.PathAndQuery;

  var routeContext = new RouteContext(httpContext);
  var router = RouteData.Routers.First(); //get the top level router

  await router.RouteAsync(routeContext); //router updates routeContext

  return new JsonResult(routeContext.RouteData.Values);
}
```

The `routeContext.RouteData` is populated by the root level router.

Comment: `RouteData.Routers.First()` Sequence contains no elements

Comment: same error as above - i don't think it is nearly this easy, yet.

Answer (score -2):

Try please;

```
var t =  ViewContext.RouteData.Values["id"];
```

Comment: please explain your answer

Comment: Thanks, but ViewContext.RouteData has the route values of the current request, what I'm looking for is something like that, but for the referral url.